# How to setup networking proxy in Godot 3

Tags: godot

All:

I am trying to use Godot Engine 3 behind a proxy, I wonder how to setup that proxy authorization in Godot?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you are in gnu/linux distributions, you can setup tor as a service, running in the background and use your DE-specifics settings or gconf/dconf for set the proxy.
Or just run:

```
torify godot
```

from your terminal.